# Updating DataGrid after changing DataTable row value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid (named m_grid) setup so that it displays the rows of a DataTable:

```
 <DataGrid name="m_grid">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Locked"
                                   Binding="{Binding '[Locked]'}"/>
           ...
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I populuate the grid in the code behind like this:

```
 DataTable l_table = Database.GetTable("SELECT * FROM Reports")
 m_grid.ItemsSource = l_table.Rows;
```

I have a context menu that has the following method attached to the click event:

```
 DataRow l_row = m_grid.SelectedItem as DataRow;
 int l_id = (int)l_row["Report ID"];
 int l_result = Database.Execute("Update [Reports] SET [Locked] = not [Locked] WHERE [Report ID]=" + l_id;
 if (l_result > 0){
      l_row["Locked"] = !l_row["Locked"];
 }
```

After click is run, the database is updated, and the value in the row has changed, but the DataGrid remains unchanged.  I have attempted to use

```
m_grid.BeginEdit();
// execute code
m_grid.CommitEdit();
```

But that has had no effect.  Am I missing something here or do I need to change up how I am binding my data to the grid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DataRow implements notifications. Instead of using Rows collection as ItemsSource (`m_grid.ItemsSource = l_table.Rows;`) use DefaultView:

```
 m_grid.ItemsSource = l_table.DefaultView;
```

It will also correctly auto-generate columns in DataGrid. And DataView supports sorting and filtering.

But note, that after such change DataGrid will contain items of type `DataRowView` (which has `Row` property). Code which uses SelectedItem should be modified as well

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but was getting crashing issues when sorting the columns because of how I was doing the binding (which worked for the DataRow, but not for the DataRowView).